# How to set plot bands in achartengine android?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine to display a chart in android. I want to make the background color green for a range of values of y (for eg 120 to 160) and rest I want to appear as white. is it possible to achieve? i can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported in AChartEngine.

However, you can download the code and write the feature yourself.